# CUDA Graph Problem: Results not computed for the first iteration

Tags: cuda, fft, cufft, cuda-graphs

I am trying to utilize CUDA Graphs for the computation of Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) using CUDA's cuFFT APIs.

I modified the [sample FFT code present on Github](https://github.com/drufat/cuda-examples/blob/master/cuda/fft.cu) into the following FFT code using CUDA Graphs:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "device_functions.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cufft.h>

// Complex data type
typedef float2 Complex;
static __device__  inline Complex ComplexScale(Complex, float);
static __device__  inline Complex ComplexMul(Complex, Complex);
static __global__ void ComplexPointwiseMulAndScale(Complex*, const Complex*, int, float);

#define CUDA_CALL( call )               \
    {                                       \
    cudaError_t result = call;              \
    if ( cudaSuccess != result )            \
        std::cerr << "CUDA error " << result << " in " << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ": " << cudaGetErrorString( result ) << " (" << #call << ")" << std::endl;  \
    }

#define CUDA_FFT_CALL( call )               \
    {                                       \
    cufftResult result = call;              \
    if ( CUFFT_SUCCESS != result )            \
        std::cerr << "FFT error " << result << " in " << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ": " <<  result  << std::endl;  \
    }

// The filter size is assumed to be a number smaller than the signal size
#define SIGNAL_SIZE        10
#define FILTER_KERNEL_SIZE  4

static __device__ inline Complex ComplexScale(Complex a, float s)
{
    Complex c;
    c.x = s * a.x;
    c.y = s * a.y;
    return c;
}

// Complex multiplication
static __device__ inline Complex ComplexMul(Complex a, Complex b)
{
    Complex c;
    c.x = a.x * b.x - a.y * b.y;
    c.y = a.x * b.y + a.y * b.x;
    return c;
}

// Complex pointwise multiplication
static __global__ void ComplexPointwiseMulAndScale(Complex* a, const Complex* b, int size, float scale)
{
    const int numThreads = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    const int threadID = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    for (int i = threadID; i < size; i += numThreads)
    {
        a[i] = ComplexScale(ComplexMul(a[i], b[i]), scale);
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("[simpleCUFFT] is starting...\n");

    int minRadius = FILTER_KERNEL_SIZE / 2;
    int maxRadius = FILTER_KERNEL_SIZE - minRadius;
    int padded_data_size = SIGNAL_SIZE + maxRadius;

    // Allocate HOST Memories 
    Complex* h_signal = (Complex*)malloc(sizeof(Complex) * SIGNAL_SIZE); //host signal
    Complex* h_filter_kernel = (Complex*)malloc(sizeof(Complex) * FILTER_KERNEL_SIZE); //host filter    
    Complex* h_padded_signal= (Complex*)malloc(sizeof(Complex) * padded_data_size); // host Padded signal 
    Complex* h_padded_filter_kernel = (Complex*)malloc(sizeof(Complex) * padded_data_size); // host Padded filter kernel    
    Complex* h_convolved_signal = (Complex*)malloc(sizeof(Complex) * padded_data_size); // to store convolution RESULTS 
    memset(h_convolved_signal, 0, padded_data_size * sizeof(Complex));

    //Allocate DEVICE Memories  
    Complex* d_signal; //device signal
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_signal, sizeof(Complex) * padded_data_size);
    Complex* d_filter_kernel;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_filter_kernel, sizeof(Complex) * padded_data_size); //device kernel    

    //CUDA GRAPH
    bool graphCreated = false;
    cudaGraph_t graph;
    cudaGraphExec_t instance;
    cudaStream_t stream;
    cudaStreamCreate(&stream);

    // CUFFT plan   
    cufftHandle plan;
    CUDA_FFT_CALL(cufftPlan1d(&plan, padded_data_size, CUFFT_C2C, 1));  
    cufftSetStream(plan, stream); // bind plan to the stream

    // Initalize the memory for the signal
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < SIGNAL_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        h_signal[i].x = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
        h_signal[i].y = 0;
    }

    // Initalize the memory for the filter
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < FILTER_KERNEL_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        h_filter_kernel[i].x = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
        h_filter_kernel[i].y = 0;
    }

    //REPEAT 3 times
    int nRepeatationsNeeded = 3;
    for (int repeatations = 0; repeatations < nRepeatationsNeeded; repeatations++) 
    {
        std::cout << "\n\n" << "Repeatation ------ " << repeatations << std::endl;
    
        if (!graphCreated)
        {
            //Start Graph Recording --------------!!!!!!!!
            CUDA_CALL(cudaStreamBeginCapture(stream, cudaStreamCaptureModeGlobal));
                
            //Pad Data                      
            CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpyAsync(h_padded_signal + 0, h_signal, SIGNAL_SIZE * sizeof(Complex), cudaMemcpyHostToHost, stream));
            memset(h_padded_signal + SIGNAL_SIZE, 0, (padded_data_size - SIGNAL_SIZE) * sizeof(Complex));
            //CUDA_CALL(cudaMemsetAsync(h_padded_signal + SIGNAL_SIZE, 0, (padded_data_size - SIGNAL_SIZE) * sizeof(Complex), stream));
                    
            CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpyAsync(h_padded_filter_kernel + 0, h_filter_kernel + minRadius, maxRadius * sizeof(Complex), cudaMemcpyHostToHost, stream));
            /*CUDA_CALL(cudaMemsetAsync(h_padded_filter_kernel + maxRadius, 0, (padded_data_size - FILTER_KERNEL_SIZE) * sizeof(Complex), stream));*/
            memset(h_padded_filter_kernel + maxRadius, 0, (padded_data_size - FILTER_KERNEL_SIZE) * sizeof(Complex));
            CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpyAsync(h_padded_filter_kernel + padded_data_size - minRadius, h_filter_kernel, minRadius * sizeof(Complex), cudaMemcpyHostToHost, stream));
        
            // MemCpy H to D
            CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpyAsync(d_signal, h_padded_signal, sizeof(Complex) * padded_data_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream)); //Signal
            CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpyAsync(d_filter_kernel, h_padded_filter_kernel, sizeof(Complex) * padded_data_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream)); //Kernel

            //COMPUTE FFT               
            CUDA_FFT_CALL(cufftExecC2C(plan, (cufftComplex*)d_signal, (cufftComplex*)d_signal, CUFFT_FORWARD)); // Transform signal 
            CUDA_FFT_CALL(cufftExecC2C(plan, (cufftComplex*)d_filter_kernel, (cufftComplex*)d_filter_kernel, CUFFT_FORWARD)); // Transform kernel    
            ComplexPointwiseMulAndScale << <64, 1, 0, stream >> > (d_signal, d_filter_kernel, padded_data_size, 1.0f / padded_data_size); // Multiply and normalize    
            CUDA_CALL(cudaGetLastError());
            CUDA_FFT_CALL(cufftExecC2C(plan, (cufftComplex*)d_signal, (cufftComplex*)d_signal, CUFFT_INVERSE)); // Transform signal back

            // Copy device memory to host           
            CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpyAsync(h_convolved_signal, d_signal, sizeof(Complex) * padded_data_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream));

            //END Graph Recording
            CUDA_CALL(cudaStreamEndCapture(stream, &graph));
            CUDA_CALL(cudaGraphInstantiate(&instance, graph, NULL, NULL, 0));
            graphCreated = true;            
        }
        else
        {
            CUDA_CALL(cudaGraphLaunch(instance, stream));
            CUDA_CALL(cudaStreamSynchronize(stream));
        }
        //verify results
        for (int i = 0; i < SIGNAL_SIZE; i++)
            std::cout << "index: " << i << ", fft: " << h_convolved_signal[i].x << std::endl;
    }

    //Destroy CUFFT context
    cufftDestroy(plan);

    // cleanup memory
    cudaStreamDestroy(stream);
    free(h_signal);
    free(h_filter_kernel);
    free(h_padded_signal);
    free(h_padded_filter_kernel);
    cudaFree(d_signal);
    cudaFree(d_filter_kernel);

    return 0;
}
```

**PROBLEM:** The Output of the above program is below, in which it can be seen that the values of the result are also `ZEROS` for the first iteration. How can I resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results are zero for the first iteration, because for the first iteration, the work is all issued in capture mode.

In capture mode, *no CUDA work actually gets done*.  From [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#creating-a-graph-using-stream-capture):

> When a stream is being captured, work launched into the stream is not enqueued for execution.

I pointed you to this same area of the documentation in a comment to your last question.  You might wish to read the entire programming guide section on graphs, and there are also [blogs available](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-graphs/).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out again. I did read the blog a few times (always take your suggestions seriously) but somehow just skipped from my mind....Thanks again :)